# javascript Buffer from several variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

How is it possible in javascript to obtain the `b` Buffer in a way simpler than the following?

```
  var num=6553599

  var a = new Buffer(4); 
  a.writeInt32LE(num); 

  var up=a.readUInt8(2); 
  var mid=a.readUInt8(1);   
  var low=a.readUInt8(0);    

  var b=new Buffer(6);
  b.writeUInt8('T'.charCodeAt(0),0);      
  b.writeUInt8(up  ,1); 
  b.writeUInt8(mid ,2);
  b.writeUInt8(low ,3); 
  b.writeUInt8(0   ,4); 
  b.writeUInt8(1   ,5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is not an issue you can use the string representation of buffers to work with them more easily.

Usually I prefer the hex representation of buffers since they're easier to read and it is easy to count bytes this way.

```
var bConcat = (a, b) => new Buffer(a.toString("hex") + b.toString("hex"), "hex");
var reducer = (acc, current)=> bConcat(acc, current);
var num=6553599
var a = new Buffer(4);
var t = 'T'.charCodeAt(0);
a.writeInt32LE(num); 
var head = new Buffer(t.toString(16), "hex");
var tail = new Buffer("0001", "hex");
var b = [head, a.slice(0,3).reverse(), tail].reduce(reducer);
```